# Bibliography not seen in the pdf file

Tags: bibliographies

I have created a bib file the contents of which are :

```
@article{han2014semantic,
  title={Semantic context-aware service composition for building automation system},
  author={Han, Son N and Lee, Gyu Myoung and Crespi, Noel},
  journal={Industrial Informatics, IEEE Transactions on},
  volume={10},
  number={1},
  pages={752--761},
  year={2014},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{karademir2013dynamic,
  title={Dynamic interactive voice response (IVR) platform},
  author={Karademir, Ramazan and Heves, Emre},
  booktitle={EUROCON, 2013 IEEE},
  pages={98--104},
  year={2013},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{xu2010design,
  title={Design of hierarchical and configurable IVR system},
  author={Xu, Shanchuan and Gao, Wanlin and Li, Zhen and Zhang, Shuliang and Zhao, Jianing},
  booktitle={Computational Intelligence and Natural Computing Proceedings (CINC), 2010 Second International Conference on},
  volume={2},
  pages={205--208},
  year={2010},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

When I include it in my document with,

```
\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

I don't get my list of references. What is the issue here?

Comment: The standard setting for JabRef certainly do include `number` on the Optional Fields table for a `article` entry. Moreover, you can add any fields you like on the BibTeX source tab or customise the appearance of entry types in the Preferences. So I'm not quite sure where the real issue is here!

Comment: Jabref is just some tool to make working on a simple text file more pleasing to the eye. It is a text file and you can treat it that way. Or force Jabref to do behave a certain way.

Comment: @Johannes_B please see the edited question

Comment: @subhamsoni: Do you run `bibtex` at all?

Comment: Creating a list of references in a LaTeX document is independent of JabRef (as @Johannes_B says, it's a nice front end for editing `.bib` files but nothing more). The usual questions that apply here are 'Did you run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX?' and 'Does your LaTeX file have any citations in it?'.

Comment: I want to list all the contents of the bib file. Then why is citation required?

Comment: @subhamsoni LaTeX/BibTeX can't just assume you mean 'everything' if there are no citations. Try adding `\nocite{*}` to your input then doing LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX/LaTeX.